# Changing JavaScript variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is my program skeleton http://jsfiddle.net/zhwzY/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btnSend").click(function(){ 

    var option = {
      'delay' : false,
      'helpSpanDisplay' : 'help-block',
      'disableSubmitBtn' : false
    };

    if($('#agree').is(':checked')){
        form_input = 'input:not("#reason")';            
    }else{      
        form_input = 'input';   
    }       


    var metric = [
      [ form_input, 'presence', 'Please fill this textbox!']
    ];



    $("#frm").nod(metric, option);      

});
```

});

From the snippet, I try to make variable "form_input" to switch to a new value depend on the checkbox. With this method, I can prevent NOD (validation plugins) from validating unecessary input. But the variable "form_input" is not changing to the new value upon updating.

Please help.

P/s : No external reference to the NOD library in jsFiddle.

Comment: Seems to update the variable fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/zhwzY/2/

Comment: What "NOD" library are you using? Please link it. Btw, in jsfiddle you can add special external resources in the left bar.

Comment: What i want to do is.. updating 'form_input' variable outside the click() event, like this [http://jsfiddle.net/zhwzY/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/zhwzY/5/)

I dont know if this make sense..

Comment: @Bergi .. this one https://github.com/chriso/node-validator ...